# Feature extraction in weka

Tags: weka, text-mining

I have a classification problem , the dataset consists of two attributes only (text,category) . I used StringToWordVector filter to add attributes .I face a diffeculty to decide which attributes to take .

I tried to use batch filter (AttributeSelection-Bestfirst search,CfsSubsetEEval) to reduce # of features .After applying the filter ,I got around 10 attributes from 2000!.

Can you advise me what strategy to follow in order to select the most useful features?

Thank you